# Disable CSS specific page

Tags: css

I want disable one specific page of the default css, and i want use my css on the specific page. I don't know it is posibble?

I use Blank State plugin, for create blank page, but css its on the blank pages, but i want my css use on the specific blank pages.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/blank-slate/

So, i have one page, that name: test-area-7
Code:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script', 99);
function my_script()
{
    if(is_page( 'test-area-7' )){
        wp_dequeue_script('fpw_styles_css');
    }
}
```

EDITED

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script', 99);
function my_script()
{
    if(is_page( 'test-area-7' )){
        wp_dequeue_script('/wp-content/themes/colormag/style.css');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of denqueue_script, why not put the conditional "if not the page" then "load my css"

```
function theme_styles() {
  if(!is_page( 'your-page-slug' )){
     wp_enqueue_style('theme-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/main.css');
  }else{
    wp_enqueue_style('my-custom-page-css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/custom.css');
  }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Place that in functions.php and should work. Not tested that though.

Answer (score 0):

Disable CSS specific page for use conditional tag.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script', 99);
function my_script()
{
    if(is_page( 'Page name' )){
        wp_dequeue_script('fpw_styles_css');
    }
}
```

> EDIT

```
 wp_dequeue_script('Your css name or id');
```

> EDIT

Please check this link  for more :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

[How to use wp_dequeue_style() for style enqueued in WP_Widget class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182644/how-to-use-wp-dequeue-style-for-style-enqueued-in-wp-widget-class)

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme-ie', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/css/ie.css");
wp_dequeue_script('my-theme-ie');
```

Comment: Huh, it is not working. Probably I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: put your code here. update your Question

Comment: Added the code, of question.

Comment: edit my answer please check it

Comment: So on the "Your css name or id" place the path my css?

Comment: yes which name to enqueue same name to dequeue

Comment: Not working. Updated the code, on the QA, please read.
I dont know, for need the page name pleace the page name, or page URL? (I tried all variable, but did not working)

Comment: Check update answer

Comment: I'm newbie on the Wordpress, unfortunately I did not get this far
 :/